# find all integers and sub strings between 2 characters

Tags: python, regex

```
example_string = "name[0]['subName'][0][1]"
```

I would like a list of a sub strings and integers between [ and ]

the result would be

```
[0, 'subName', 0, 1]
```

I believe re.findall() would work but I'm not sure what the regex would be

Comment: where did `top` come from. I would have expected `subName`

Comment: Do you want to evaluate the items in the same step (looks like it)?

Comment: this ***screams*** XY to me. What is it you're trying to accomplish with `[0, 'subName', 0, 1]`?

Comment: @AdamSmith inb4 `eval`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`re_results = re.findall("\[(.*?)\]",example_string)` ... might work for you (assuming you dont have nested brackets)... I suspect the key you were missing was using greedy matches "[.*]" would match as big as possible, as such it captures everything from the first open bracket to the last close bracket as a single match. "[.*?]" matches as little as possible, thus only one bracket pair per single match

(you will need to manually cast to integers if thats what you actually want)

you could do something simple like

```
def castIntOrDont(x):
    try:
       return int(x)
    except ValueError:
       return x.strip("'") #strip out the extra quotes on strings

print map(castIntOrDont,re_result)  #list(map(...)) in py3
```

Comment: Your regex will also return the single quotes, something like `re.findall("\['?(.*?)'?\]", example_string)` would avoid that

Comment: or just strip them in your post processing method :P (but yeah very good point, I just overlooked them initially)

Answer (score 4):

If you know that the indexes are either singled quoted strings or integers you can use this list comprehension:

```
[ g[1:-1] if i else int(g)
  for m in re.finditer(r"\[(?:(\d+)|('.*?'))\]", example_string)
  for i, g in enumerate(m.groups()) if g is not None ]
```

All matches m in the input:

```
for m in re.finditer(r"\[(?:(\d+)|('.*?'))\]", example_string)
```

For every match: `i=0` for the integer alternative, or `i=1` for the string alternative:

```
for i, g in enumerate(m.groups()) if g is not None
```

Strip quotes or cast to an integer:

```
g[1:-1] if i else int(g)
```

Comment: +1 for explicitly allowing only expected input ... however you trade off significant amount of readability :/ but still a good answer +1